# List and image on one row appear to be warpping [bootstrap]

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, html

I want to have a list and an image side by side in one row on my webpage. I feel like I have made some errors with bootstrap because the list is ending up below the image (maybe because they take up too much space- I don't think I have too many columns and it is wrapping)

Any suggestions woould be appreciated.

Thanks

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <img class="image-two image-border" src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/15253259_1789498794648779_1451041077317337088_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM5ODUzMzg3MTkxNzgxNDg4Ng%3D%3D.2" alt="Me and Ami laughing together" /> 
            </div>
       </div>


            <!-- list of reasons I love Ami here -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-5 list-background">
              <p> Reasons I love her: </p>
                <ul> She is filled with love </ul>
                <ul> Her beautiful eyes </ul>
                <ul> Her lust for life </ul>
                <ul> The way she loves me </ul>


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-two 
{
max-width:40%;
max-height:40%;
}

.image-border {
padding:2px;
border:1px solid #021a40;
background-color: #0000ff;
}

.list-background{
display: inline-block;
background-color: yellow;
text-align: left;
border: solid;
border-radius: 25px;
max-width: 50%;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

I made a few corrections:

1. You had two `row` divs but only wanted one row. This is why they showed up as one under the other.
2. You declared your list wrong. You declare unordered lists with `<ul>` and list elements with `<li>`.
3. You need to cover all columns with Bootstrap. There are a total of 12 columns, so for example one element should take up 3 columns and the other 9. There shouldn't be any columns left.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img class="image-two image-border" src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/15253259_1789498794648779_1451041077317337088_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM5ODUzMzg3MTkxNzgxNDg4Ng%3D%3D.2" alt="Me and Ami laughing together" />
  </div>
  <!-- list of reasons I love Ami here -->
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 list-background">
    <p> Reasons I love her: </p>
    <ul>
      <li> She is filled with love </li>
      <li> Her beautiful eyes </li>
      <li> Her lust for life </li>
      <li> The way she loves me </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Stack columns inside the single row, so they are next to each other.
2. For the image, use `.img-responsive` ([`.img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images) in later versions) class, keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```css
.image-border {
  padding:2px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.list-background{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.list-background ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img class="image-two image-border img-responsive" src="https://scontent-sea1-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/15253259_1789498794648779_1451041077317337088_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM5ODUzMzg3MTkxNzgxNDg4Ng%3D%3D.2" alt="Me and Ami laughing together" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 list-background">
    <p> Reasons I love her: </p>
    <ul>
      <li> She is filled with love </li>
      <li> Her beautiful eyes </li>
      <li> Her lust for life </li>
      <li> The way she loves me </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```